# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'generator' and 'int'

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension, built-in

I was trying to create a list conformed by n sub-lists, which are conformed by a k amount of a specific number (0) using list comprehension.

The idea is that it would generate a matrix of 0 of dimensions n*k, being the raws sub-lists inside the principal list, and the columns all the objects with same index.

The code I though was something like:
`O_matrix= [(empty_list.append(0) for i in range(n_of_columns)) * n_of_raws]`

I was expecting that the (`for i in range`...) would  generate a list `[0, 0, 0,...]`, but it told me that it creates a generator even if I use the function `list()`

I also noticed that by multiplying by the number of raws doesn't produce `k` lists, but rather, one list with a length of `n*k`.

Comment: `(empty_list.append(0) for i in range(n_of_columns))` is a generator expression; `[empty_list.append(0) for i in range(n_of_columns)]` a list comprehension...

Comment: "but it told me that it creates a generator even if I use the function list()". `(empty_list.append(0) for i in range(n_of_columns))` is obviously a generator. If you call `list` on it, it *definitely creates a list*: `list(empty_list.append(0) for i in range(n_of_columns))`, and note, you are putting all of that inside it's own single-element list: `[<gen exp>]`. But, very importantly, **you shouldn't be using listcomprehensions or generator expressions for side effects**. `empty_list.append` **returns `None`** so you are creating a `list` of `None`s.

Comment: "I also noticed that by multiplying by the number of raws doesn't produce k lists, but rather, one list with a length of n*k." of course, why did you think it would work any differently? You shouldn't be using the multiplication operator here probably to begin with.

Comment: Here is what you need: `[[0 for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]`. Just that. This *could* be shortened to `[[0]*k for _ in range(n)]`. Frankly, you should probably just stick to for loops until you grasp what list comprehensions are actually doing, fundamentally, they are *sugar* they aren't necessary

Comment: You should definitely read through at least the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i